# Test snackBar occurrence in service spec

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

So, I'm writing unit tests for an Angular application. I have this errorHandlerService, with a handle() function, which receives a String or an Error class, handles it and, in the end, opens a snackBar with different messages, according to the error type.

**error-handler.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorHandlerService {

  constructor(
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) { }

   handle(errorResponse: any) {
    let msg: string;

    if (typeof errorResponse === 'string') {
      msg = errorResponse;

    } else if (errorResponse instanceof HttpErrorResponse
      && errorResponse.status >= 400 && errorResponse.status <= 499) {
        msg = 'Error processing your request.';

        if (errorResponse.status === 403) {
          msg = 'You're not allowed to execute this action.';
        }

        console.error('Error occurred', errorResponse);
     } else {
        msg = 'Error processing remote service. Try again later.';
        console.error('Error occurred', errorResponse);
     }

    this.snackBar.open(msg);
  }
}
```

My approach of testing is just to evaluate if the snackBar is opened, considering it is going to happen anyway. But how can I do it? Here it is my .spec.ts file

**error-handler.service.spec.ts**

```
describe('ErrorHandlerService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [
      { provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: {} }
    ]
}));

it('should be created', () => {
 const service: ErrorHandlerService = TestBed.get(ErrorHandlerService);
 expect(service).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should call handle function and check snackBar occurrence', () => {
  const service: ErrorHandlerService = TestBed.get(ErrorHandlerService);
  service.handle('testing error');

  expect(service.snackBar.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would declare the service above `beforeEach` and initializing it in it:

```
 let service: ErrorhandlerService;
 beforeEach(() => {.... service = TestBet.get(ErrorHandlerService); })
```

In it I will do like that:

```
let spy = spyOn(service.snackBar, "open")

service.handle(msg);
```

And then expect:

```
(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(msg)
```

Suggestion: I would put some specific name in it. Something like `Service_MethodToTest_ExpectOpenToBeCalled`.

Comment: The idea behind it worked fine. But I had to do some tricky change on it, because when spy calls the open() method, it was thrown a 'open() method does not exist error'. So I moved 'this.snackbar.open()' to a method and used it on spy.

Comment: You can do that, that's right. But that doesn't solve your problem. Now you have to test also the new method. To solve the problem with "open method does not exist error", you have to initalize the snackbar. Use TestBed in "beforeEach" for that and configureTestingModule.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert Tab for the help! It worked fine. I just had to make some adjustments, as follows:

**error-handler.service.ts (at the end of the file)**

```
   this.callSnackBar(msg);
 }

 callSnackBar(msg: string) {
   this.snackBar.open(msg);
 }
```

And in the spec.ts file I did it:

**error-handler.service.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(() => {
  service = TestBed.get(ErrorHandlerService);
});

...

it('should call handle function and check snackBar occurrence', () => {
  const spy = spyOn(service, 'callSnackBar');
  const msg = 'Service_MethodToTest_ExpectOpenToBeCalled';

  service.handle(msg);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(msg);
});
```